# mysqli insert statement not executing in php script; no error msg

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm developing a custom tshirt lab. I want to be able to save a user's uploaded image in a folder as well as make an entry in a table with its image path and id. It gets moved to the folder, but it doesn't get inserted. No errors show up as well, so I'm completely stumped on why it's not working. I'm using session variables i had declared in another page and I still don't get any errors.

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","asdasd","asdsada");

$UPLOAD_DIR = 'uploads/';
$img = $_POST['imgData'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $UPLOAD_DIR . time() . '.png';
$_SESSION["design_path"] = $file;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
$query_upload = "INSERT INTO design (image_id, customer_id, design_path, image_path) VALUES ('$_SESSION["image_id"]', '$_SESSION["customer_id"]', '$file', '$_SESSION["image_path"]')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query_upload);
if($result){
    echo "design saved";
}
?>
```

Comment: your PHP code is invalid.

Comment: unexpected T_STRING(image_id)!

Comment: Are u coding using notepad?

Comment: No I'm using sublime, I wrote the question on my desktop but I posted it from my phone. I understand the way I used the session variables are wrong, I read somewhere to try it. It didn't work without the brackets either.